# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent - Saving data in multiple tables so that _id's are saved

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: pages, headers, footers.  I have relationships set up so that Page `hasOne('App\Footer')` and `hasOne('App\Header')`.  Header and Footer each `belongTo('App\Page')`.  The pages table has `header_id` and `footer_id`.  The others have `page_id`.  When I retrieve `Page`, the header and footer are also pulled *IF* (and only if) all the id's correspond to each other.

In my controller, there's no problem saving `Page`, including the header and footer.  But since I have relationships set up, all of the ids should be correctly saved but only the `page_id` is being saved on the footers and headers table - the ids of the footers and headers are not being saved to the pages table.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public function putAddpage(Request $request)
{
    $header = new Header(['text' => $request->input('header-text')]);
    $footer = new Footer(['text' => $request->input('footer-text')]);

    $page = new Page();
    $page->title = $request->input('page-title');
    $page->some_text = $request->input('some_text');
    $page->save();

    $page->header()->save($header);
    $page->footer()->save($footer);

    return $page;
}
```

**Example DB data:**
pages: {id:12, footer_id:0, header_id:0, title:"Page Title", some_text:"blah blah blah"}
footers: {id:2, page_id:12, text:"More blah blah blah"}
headers: {id:4, page_id:12, text:"Nothing to see here"}

How do I get it so the `footer_id` and `header_id` have the correct ids saved as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you wouldn't. What I understand from your code is that `header_id` and `footer_id` shouldn't be there, you don't need them.

if you want to get the header of a page..

```
$page->header;
```

you don't need header_id on the page table for this to work! since you defined the relationship already ( page -> hasOne header )

Are you trying to achieve different behavior?

---

### Update  - Using associate

```
public function putAddpage(Request $request)
{
  // need to save or use Create method.
  // Using save()
  $header = new Header(['text' => $request->input('header-text')])->save();
  // Using create ( will save automatically )
  $footer = Footer::Create(['text' => $request->input('footer-text')]);

  $page = new Page();
  $page->title = $request->input('page-title');
  $page->some_text = $request->input('some_text');
  // now save the page
  $page->save();
  // now the page has an id. 

  // Associate header and footer ( this will set the page_id on the header and the footer ) 
  $page->header()->associate($header);
  $page->footer()->associate($footer);

  $page->save(); // not sure if you need to save now. Try removing this and see :). 

  return $page;
}
```

Comment: If I remove `header_id` and `footer_id` from the pages table, then neither will load. :(

Comment: You just need to save them. ->save() the header a the footer. Of course you need to save the page first then associate() header and footer with the page, then save them

Comment: Maybe I'm missing this "`associate()`" step, but when I try it I get a "Call to Undefined Method" error.  Once again I removed the `header_id` & `footer_id` from the pages table and now the text isn't showing (but it does when I have the 'correct' fields and ids).  Maybe you could show (in code) what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it. First is your code is already correct you just need to save the header and footer.

```
public function putAddpage(Request $request)
{
    $header = new Header(['text' => $request->input('header-text')])->save();
    $footer = new Footer(['text' => $request->input('footer-text')])->save();

    $page = new Page();
    $page->title = $request->input('page-title');
    $page->some_text = $request->input('some_text');
    $page->header_id = $header->id;
    $page->footer_id = $footer->id;
    $page->save();

    return $page;
}
```

Second assign `header_id` and `footer_id` to the page.

```
public function putAddpage(Request $request)
{
    $header = new Header(['text' => $request->input('header-text')])->save();
    $footer = new Footer(['text' => $request->input('footer-text')])->save();

    $page = new Page();
    $page->title = $request->input('page-title');
    $page->some_text = $request->input('some_text');
    $page->save();

    $page->header()->save($header);
    $page->footer()->save($footer);

    return $page;
}
```

Comment: This totally works and I am using it now with success, thank you.  Although I had to move the `save()` methods onto the variables after creating them. If I were to do this without Eloquent though, I would not be putting `page_id` in the headers & footers tables in order to get this to work properly.  I feel like though this works just as I wanted it to, I still might have some DB/relationship problems.

Comment: @DondeEstaMiCulo, please mark my answer as best answer if you found it helpful :)